# Gnome-boxes won't start on one account but will on another

Tags: gnome-boxes

Gnome-boxes begins to start then crashes on my account. However, I created another account and boxes loaded fine. I tried to delete the files in *~/.config* and *~/.share* but no luck.

When I launch from the CL I get the following error:

```
(gnome-boxes:13410): Libvirt.GObject-CRITICAL **: gvir_storage_vol_get_info: assertion 'GVIR_IS_STORAGE_VOL(vol)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)\
```

Update:
`gnome-boxes --checks` results in:

```
(gnome-boxes:2803): Boxes-WARNING **: util-app.vala:270: Failed to execute child process ?virsh? (No such file or directory)

(gnome-boxes:2803): Boxes-WARNING **: util-app.vala:250: Failed to execute child process ?restorecon? (No such file or directory)
• The CPU is capable of virtualization: yes
• The KVM module is loaded: yes
• Libvirt KVM guest available: no
• Boxes storage pool available: no
    Could not get “gnome-boxes” storage pool information from libvirt. Make sure “virsh -c qemu:///session pool-dumpxml gnome-boxes” is working.
• The SELinux context is default: no

Report bugs to <https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gnome-boxes>.
Boxes home page: <https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes>.`
```

Thanks in advance for any advice how to correct this problem.

Comment: What happens when you `gnome-boxes --checks` in the `terminal`?

Comment: `(gnome-boxes:11116): Boxes-WARNING **: util-app.vala:270: Failed to execute child process ?virsh? (No such file or directory)

(gnome-boxes:11116): Boxes-WARNING **: util-app.vala:250: Failed to execute child process ?restorecon? (No such file or directory)
• The CPU is capable of virtualization: yes
• The KVM module is loaded: yes
• Libvirt KVM guest available: no
• Boxes storage pool available: no
    Could not get “gnome-boxes” storage pool information from libvirt. Make sure “virsh -c qemu:///session pool-dumpxml gnome-boxes” is working.
•SELinux context is default: no`

Comment: Please put that kind of text into the question, instead of into comments. It's terribly hard to read. Copy/paste into question, and use the code formatting icon to keep it pretty. If you Google "gnome-boxes crash", or something similar, you'll get a whole lot of hits from others having similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this issue as well-- gnome-boxes would crash with that seg fault whenever I tried to open it. Here's what I did to fix it.

After uninstalling gnome-boxes (`sudo apt remove gnome-boxes && sudo apt autoremove`), I ran `sudo grep -rlI "gnome-boxes" ~` to get a list of files in my home directory that had the phrase "gnome-boxes" in it. It found several files, and I specifically deleted these:

```
./.config/libvirt/qemu/boxes-unknown.xml
./.config/libvirt/qemu/boxes-unknown-2.xml
./.cache/libvirt/qemu/log/boxes-unknown.log
./.cache/libvirt/qemu/log/boxes-unknown-2.log
./.cache/libvirt/qemu/log/boxes-unknown-3.log
```

(I am guessing that really all you need to delete will be the xml files).

After re-installing gnome-boxes (`sudo apt install gnome-boxes`), all is well and gnome-boxes is no longer crashing with the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was clearing the *.xml Files in `~/.config/libvirt/qemu`. There are different .xml files depending on your virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to do `find | grep boxes` from my home directory, and remove all the directories I found boxes stuff in, including ~/.config/libvirt.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was:

$find | grep boxes
then
$rm -rf ./.config/libvirt/storage/autostart/gnome-boxes.xml